# How to set Roslynator settings so they stick

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using the Roslynator code analyzer extension (v1.5.12) in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.3.5). I would like to temporarily turn off a refactoring. I go to Tools | Options, Roslynator, Refactorings and uncheck RR0015 Call 'ConfigureAwait(false)'.

The refactoring does not turn off immediately in the code, so I close Visual Studio and reopen it. When I look at the settings again it has been re-enabled.

I have tried with Use config file checked and with it unchecked (that setting does stick).

Looks like a bug, but I'm wondering if maybe there is a work-around, like a config file somewhere that I can edit. I searched for roslynator.config and could not find it.

EDIT: Using .NET Core

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/HowToConfigureAnalyzers.md ?

Comment: thanks. yes, saw that. I was hoping for something that affects the VS installation. I may fall back on that though, as long as I can do it w/o affecting the solution/project for others on the team who aren't using Roslynator.

Comment: Was going to give that a try, but ran into a difference in how .NET Core configures analyzers. I would really like to avoid applying this to the solution/project so I'm going to hold off for now.

Comment: anyone figured this out yet? seeing this myself + would rather not add a file to the repo